# How to perform a has many through statement using laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Say i have three tables users,users_groups and groups.How can i get the user's groups through the users_groups table?

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'users';
}

class Groups extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'groups';
}

class Usergroups extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'users_groups';
}
```

Comment: What you are looking for is a _Many to Many_ relationship. You can see the documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many) . I hope that helps!

Comment: Can you provide me an example for my scenario

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per your request, I've put together a simple example for your specific use case:

#### The Tables:

Eloquent suggests creating 3 database tables in such a scenario: `users`, `groups` and `group_user`.

The Laravel [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many) states that:

> The `group_user` table's name is derived from the aplhabetical order of the related model names.

The `group_user` table should contain the columns `user_id` and `group_id` which will contain the primary keys of group and user entries. The `group_user` table is what's known as a pivot table.

This conforms to [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) (if you're interested).

#### The Models:

The `User` model should contain the following code:

```
<?php 

class User extends Eloquent {

    //...Other code…

    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Group');
    }

}
```

The `Group` model should contain the following code:

```
<?php

class Group extends Eloquent {

    //...Other code…

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

    //...Other code…

}
```

You do **not** need a `UserGroup` model as found in your question.

#### Usage:

In order to retrieve all groups to which a particular user belongs you would do the following:

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
$user_groups = $user->groups();
```

Similarly in order to retrieve all users belonging to a particular group you would do the following:

```
$group = Group::find($group_id);
$group_users = $group->users();
```

In order to add/remove a user to a group would would do the following:

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
//Add a user
$user->groups()->attach($group_id);
//Detach a user
$user->groups()->detach($group_id);
```

#### Other:

You should read more in the Laravel docs about pivot tables [here](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) and about defining foreign keys (for your pivot table) in your migrations [here](http://laravel.com/docs/schema#foreign-keys).

I hope that helps!